# Не меняется fps камеры на raspberry pi

Tags: python, linux, opencv, камера, raspberry-pi

Имеется `raspberry pi`, к которой подключена вебка `genius WideCam 1050`.

Требуется обрабатывать видео с камеры, однако `30 fps` она не тянет и кадры сильно отстают.

Пробовал менять `fps` в самом `opencv` ([python](/questions/tagged/python), `cv2`) с помощью `set`, однако выдает ошибку, что флаг `CV_CAP_PROP_FPS` не найден.

Пробовал напрямую указать `5`, но `fps` остается прежним.

В гугле нашел информацию, что `fps` меняется в `v4l2` командой `"v4l2-ctl -p %fps%"`, однако у меня, какой бы `fps` я не указал, оно выдает сообщение, что установлен fps 30.000. Хоть 10, хоть 60 - все равно ставит 30.

Может ли быть причина в камере? Или можно как-то в opencv очищать буфер кадров, чтобы при чтении кадра считывался текущий, а не который был получен пару секунд назад?

Answer (score 1):

Доступные настройки подключенной камеры (включая fps) можно посмотреть и попробовать изменить через программу [guvcview](http://guvcview.sourceforge.net/index.html). В зависимости от конкретной модели камеры и установленных в системе драйверов будут доступны разные опции. По крайней мере это позволит понять, в камере ли дело.

Не лучший вариант, но получение актуального по времени снимка можно свести к получению первого снимка после создания экземпляра VideoCapture c последующим вызовом метода release() в цикле.

```
from time import sleep
import numpy as np
import cv2

while(True):
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

    ret, frame = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    cv2.imshow('frame',gray)

    cap.release()
    sleep(0.1) # Time in seconds.

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```